# IOS Charts highlight specific labels on X-axis and dashed gridline only in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am trying to have different colours for the labels on the X-axis based on the current date of the month, but I can't seem to individually configure them. I am also trying to have a gridline that has dashes for the midline and the ceiling line would be without dashes. This is on the left axis. But I can't seem to set it individually as well.

Currently how it is:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

My code so far:

```
func setBarChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [String]){
    barChartView.noDataTextColor = UIColor.white
    barChartView.noDataText = "No data for the chart"
    barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataPoint = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i])!)
        dataEntry.append(dataPoint)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntry, label: "BPM")
    let chartData =  BarChartData()
    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    chartData.setDrawValues(false)
    chartData.barWidth = Double(0.5)
    chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 0, green: 158/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1)]


    let formatter: ChartFormatter = ChartFormatter ()
    formatter.setValues(values: dataPoints)
    let floatValue: [CGFloat] = [4,4]
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
    barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 141/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
    barChartView.getAxis(.right).labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 141/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
    barChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.clear
    barChartView.getAxis(.right).axisLineColor = UIColor.clear
    barChartView.getAxis(.left).axisLineColor = UIColor.clear
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
    barChartView.rightAxis.labelCount = Int(2)
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    barChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
    barChartView.leftAxis.gridLineWidth = CGFloat(1.5)
    barChartView.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = floatValue
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    barChartView.data = chartData
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality isn't available in the library.

- https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/3317
- https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2925

---

However, that should not stop you from implementing it yourself and maybe even adding it to the library.

As a starting point, look at [XAxisRenderer](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/c43b6b6070c15af5f2a99dc57a6e62487921aba7/Source/Charts/Renderers/XAxisRenderer.swift) that has `drawLabels(context:pos:anchor:)`.

Here, it basically loops through `xAxis.entries` and draws each label by calling `drawLabel(context:formattedLabel:x:y:attributes:constrainedToSize:anchor:angleRadians:)`, passing it a `labelAttrs` that has the information regarding the color to apply.
But currently... `labelAttrs` is set before the loop with one color referenced from `xAxis.labelTextColor`.

The key over here is setting `labelAttrs[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor]` to a color relative to the entry, say, near about this line:

```
let label = xAxis.valueFormatter?.stringForValue(xAxis.entries[i], axis: xAxis) ?? ""
```

Which probably would be best if the color were to be provided by `xAxis.valueFormatter` as well, and that in turn requires changes to `IAxisValueFormatter` in order to provide for it.

I hope this helps you in some way.